How to iterate over a MS Office Word document in Python using python-docx library or similar and extract all objects (Paragraphs, Tables, etc.)?
I am trying to create a  script to loop through a Word document to identify and extract all of the relevant objects in the order they appear to the user "On screen", basically a document parser. My end goal is to dump that information into an Excel workbook 'line-by-line', but that part is not as difficult to manage and do, what's more difficult is "seeing" and "identifying" the different object types. I was able to get my code to work for normal paragraph objects and table objects but I can't seem to get it to work when I want to add in images to the mix.
This the code I wrote to try and accomplish what I want:
# Importing necessary libraries and modules
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Tk

import docx
from docx import Document

import win32com.client as win32
import os


rootMain = tkinter.Tk(); rootMain.withdraw

# Pick the required word file you need to extract information from
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_path)
src_doc = Document(file_path)
# Modify file path string to be accepted by win32com
file_path32 = file_path.replace("/","\\")
directory = os.path.split(file_path)[0]
directory32 = directory.replace("/","\\")

rootMain.destroy()

wrd = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
exl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wrd.Visible = True
exl.Visible = True

# The reason why I have this here is so I can run the 'ListParaWordClean' function and use the cleaned up word document in the python-docx context
src_doc32 = wrd.Documents.Open(file_path32)

# This function cleans up the word document of choice by converting all bullet points/lists (ListParagraph Objects) into Paragraph objects 
def ListParaWordClean(Doc):
    try:
        wrd = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
        wrd.Visible = True

        Doc.ConvertNumbersToText()

        print("Clean-up code executed successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

ListParaWordClean(src_doc32)
temp_src32 = src_doc32.SaveAs(str(directory32)+"\\"+'TempDoc.docx')

temp_src = Document(str(directory)+'/TempDoc.docx')

# This is the excel workbook where I want to dump the information into eventually
wb = exl.Workbooks.Add()


Then, the main loop code where I am looking to identify word objects:
i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
# I'm using print statements to check if portions of loop worked
for element in temp_src.element.body:
    if isinstance(element, docx.oxml.text.paragraph.CT_P):
        # Do something
        print('Paragraph ' + str(i) + ': ' + element.text)
        i+=1
    elif isinstance(element, docx.oxml.table.CT_Tbl):
        # Do something
        print('Table ' + str(j) + ' found!')
        i+=1
        j+=1
    elif isinstance(element,docx.shape.InlineShape):
        # Do something
        print('Picture ' + str(k) + ' found!')
        i+=1
        k+=1

So the following worked for me for a test Word document which looks like this:
Page 1 of Test Word Document
Page 2 of Test Word Document
The resultant output of the print statements is as follows:
C:/Users/■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■/TestOpen.docx
Clean-up code executed successfully!
Paragraph 1: THIS IS A TEST DOCUMENT
Paragraph 2: CHAPTER 1— GENERAL
Paragraph 3: Section 1.01               First Section
Paragraph 4: This is some content, followed by more bullet points.
Paragraph 5: A. Bullet point A, content is content.
Paragraph 6: Underneath the content is more content.
Paragraph 7: B. B Bullet point, it shall be written as such.
Paragraph 8: (1)        (1) is the quantity of stuff to be obtained.
Paragraph 9: 
Paragraph 10: As such, this document is to be concluded.
Paragraph 11: [End of Section]
Paragraph 12: Section 1.02      —
Paragraph 13: A.
Paragraph 14: (1)
Paragraph 15: [End of Section]
Paragraph 16: CHAPTER 2—
Paragraph 17: Section 2.01

Table 1 found!
Paragraph 19: 
Paragraph 20: CHAPTER 3—        Another Chapter another day
Paragraph 21: Section 3.01       Typing some stuff and some more
Paragraph 22:
Paragraph 23: 
Paragraph 24: Picture of some mountains
Table 2 found!
Paragraph 26: 
Paragraph 27:
Paragraph 28: This is a picture of a forest
Paragraph 29: [End of Document]

Which clearly shows that the code is working fine for Paragraph objects and Table objects and they are being identified, but the 2 images are not being identified. For some reason the element.docx.shape.InlineShape class is not working for identifying images.
I have tried many other methods of trying to solve this problem including resorting to VBA but it's proven to be challenging for me. I even tried to separate each object collections such as doc.paragraphs and doc.tables and doc.inline_shapes but the problem is that this does not preserve the order they appear in the word document if using this approach.

Maybe you can get some idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566764/how-to-extract-image-from-table-in-ms-word-document-with-docx-library?rq=2
